# Specify the developement version of a python module

Tags: python, python-module, picos-api

I want to add a new class to [PICOS, a python module](https://picos-api.gitlab.io/picos/). I installed it the normal way a long time ago. But now I have downloaded the source and I a am trying to make some changes.

The problem is that I cannot manage to ask python to load the module from the development folder and not the normal folder.

```
reload(picos.constraint)

Out[22]: <module 'picos.constraint' from '/home/optimi/bzffourn/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/picos/constraint.pyc'>
```

while the source code are here:

```
/home/optimi/bzffourn/ZIB/python_scripts/pyMathProg/picos
```

So the changes I make are not considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you do it: [Override Python import order](http://www.hasenkopf2000.net/wiki/page/how-override-pythons-module-import-order/).
Just change your import to this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/optimi/bzffourn/ZIB/python_scripts/pyMathProg/picos")
import picos.constraint
```